# Celery, Django, Redis meet Error 99 when deploy with docker

Tags: django, docker, redis, docker-compose, celery

I'm trying to deploy my Django project and celery in docker, and I want to use redis as the result backend.

Django version: `1.11.3`

Celery version: `4.1.0`

My `docker-compose.yml` are as follows:

```
python:
  image: python:latest
  restart: always
  expose:
    - "8000"
  volumes:
    - ~/django/902Scratch/API:/home/django/API 
    - /var/sb2_files:/var/sb2_files 
    - /home/tuopinpin/JudgeServer/tests/test_case:/test_case 
  links:
    - celery:celery
  command: bash -c " cd /home/django/API &&  python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
  ports:
        - "0.0.0.0:8000:8000"

celery:
  image: python:latest
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ~/django/902Scratch/API:/home/django/API 
    - /var/sb2_files:/var/sb2_files 
  user: nobody
  depends_on:
    - redis
  links:
    - redis:redis
  command: bash -c " cd /home/django/API && celery -A API worker"

redis:
  image: redis:alpine
  restart: always
  expose:
    - '6379'
  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
```

The celery setting in django are like follows:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"
CELERY_BACKEND_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/1'
```

and `celery -A proj report` returns these settings:

```
celery_1        | software -> celery:4.1.0 (latentcall) kombu:4.1.0 py:3.6.5
celery_1        |             billiard:3.5.0.3 redis:2.10.5
celery_1        | platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
celery_1        | loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
celery_1        | settings -> transport:redis results:redis
celery_1        | 
celery_1        | ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES: {
celery_1        |  }
celery_1        | ADMINS: []
celery_1        | ALLOWED_HOSTS: ['*']
celery_1        | APPEND_SLASH: True
celery_1        | AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS: 
celery_1        |     ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
celery_1        | AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS: '********'
celery_1        | AUTH_USER_MODEL: 'scratch_api.BaseUser'
celery_1        | AVATAR_AUTO_GENERATE_SIZES: 
celery_1        |     (160, 160)
celery_1        | AVATAR_CACHE_ENABLED: False
celery_1        | AVATAR_CHANGE_TEMPLATE: 'avatar/change_avatar.html'
celery_1        | AVATAR_CLEANUP_DELETED: True
celery_1        | AVATAR_DEFAULT_URL: 'img/user_img.png'
celery_1        | AVATAR_GRAVATAR_FIELD: 'username'
celery_1        | AVATAR_MAX_AVATARS_PER_USER: 1
celery_1        | AVATAR_PROVIDERS: 
celery_1        |     ('avatar.providers.PrimaryAvatarProvider',
celery_1        |  'avatar.providers.DefaultAvatarProvider')
celery_1        | BASE_DIR: '/home/django/API'
celery_1        | CACHES: {
celery_1        |  'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
celery_1        | CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS: 'default'
celery_1        | CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX: '********'
celery_1        | CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS: 600
celery_1        | CELERY_BACKEND_URL: 'redis://redis:6379/0'
celery_1        | CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT: 'redis'
celery_1        | CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'redis://redis:6379/0'
celery_1        | CELERY_IMPORTS: 
celery_1        |     ('scratch_api.tasks',)
celery_1        | CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'redis'
celery_1        | CKEDITOR_CONFIGS: {
celery_1        |     'default': {   'extraPlugins': 'codesnippet,uploadimage,widget,lineutils',
celery_1        |                    'language': 'zh-Hans',
celery_1        |                    'removePlugins': 'elementspath',
celery_1        |                    'skin': 'moono',
celery_1        |                    'toolbar': 'full'},
celery_1        |     'qa_ckeditor': {   'extraPlugins': 'codesnippet,uploadimage,widget,lineutils',
celery_1        |                        'language': 'zh-Hans',
celery_1        |                        'removePlugins': 'elementspath'}}
celery_1        | CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND: 'pillow'
celery_1        | CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH: 'course/'
celery_1        | COMMENTS_APP: 'fluent_comments'
celery_1        | CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS: 
celery_1        |     ('Authorization',)
celery_1        | CORS_ALLOW_METHODS: 
celery_1        |     ('GET', 'POST')
celery_1        | CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL: True
celery_1        | CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK: 'bootstrap3'
celery_1        | CSRF_COOKIE_AGE: 31449600
celery_1        | CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN: None
celery_1        | CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY: False
celery_1        | CSRF_COOKIE_NAME: 'csrftoken'
celery_1        | CSRF_COOKIE_PATH: '/'
celery_1        | CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE: False
celery_1        | CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW: 'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
celery_1        | CSRF_HEADER_NAME: 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
celery_1        | CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS: []
celery_1        | CSRF_USE_SESSIONS: False
celery_1        | DATABASES: {
celery_1        |     'default': {   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
celery_1        |                    'NAME': '/home/django/API/db.sqlite3'}}
celery_1        | DATABASE_ROUTERS: '********'
celery_1        | DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE: 2621440
celery_1        | DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS: 1000
celery_1        | DATETIME_FORMAT: 'N j, Y, P'
celery_1        | DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS: ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
celery_1        |  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
celery_1        |  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
celery_1        |  '%Y-%m-%d',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%Y',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%y']
celery_1        | DATE_FORMAT: 'N j, Y'
celery_1        | DATE_INPUT_FORMATS: ['%Y-%m-%d',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%Y',
celery_1        |  '%m/%d/%y',
celery_1        |  '%b %d %Y',
celery_1        |  '%b %d, %Y',
celery_1        |  '%d %b %Y',
celery_1        |  '%d %b, %Y',
celery_1        |  '%B %d %Y',
celery_1        |  '%B %d, %Y',
celery_1        |  '%d %B %Y',
celery_1        |  '%d %B, %Y']
celery_1        | DEBUG: True
celery_1        | DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS: False
celery_1        | DECIMAL_SEPARATOR: '.'
celery_1        | DEFAULT_CHARSET: 'utf-8'
celery_1        | DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE: 'text/html'
celery_1        | DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER: 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
celery_1        | DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE: 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
celery_1        | DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL: 'tuopinpin@www.tuopinpin.com'
celery_1        | DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE: ''
celery_1        | DEFAULT_TABLESPACE: ''
celery_1        | DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS: []
celery_1        | EMAIL_BACKEND: 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
celery_1        | EMAIL_HOST: 'smtpdm.aliyun.com'
celery_1        | EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD: '********'
celery_1        | EMAIL_HOST_USER: 'tuopinpin@www.tuopinpin.com'
celery_1        | EMAIL_PORT: 25
celery_1        | EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE: None
celery_1        | EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE: '********'
celery_1        | EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX: '[Django] '
celery_1        | EMAIL_TIMEOUT: None
celery_1        | EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME: False
celery_1        | EMAIL_USE_SSL: False
celery_1        | EMAIL_USE_TLS: False
celery_1        | FILE_CHARSET: 'utf-8'
celery_1        | FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS: None
celery_1        | FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS: ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
celery_1        |  'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
celery_1        | FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE: 2621440
celery_1        | FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS: None
celery_1        | FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR: None
celery_1        | FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK: 0
celery_1        | FIXTURE_DIRS: []
celery_1        | FLUENT_COMMENTS_EXCLUDE_FIELDS: 
celery_1        |     ('name', 'email', 'url', 'title')
celery_1        | FLUENT_COMMENTS_FORM_CLASS: 'API.comments.CommentForm'
celery_1        | FLUENT_COMMENTS_USE_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION: False
celery_1        | FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME: None
celery_1        | FORMAT_MODULE_PATH: None
celery_1        | FORM_RENDERER: 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
celery_1        | IGNORABLE_404_URLS: []
celery_1        | INSTALLED_APPS: ['django.contrib.admin',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.auth',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.sessions',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.messages',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
celery_1        |  'scratch_api.apps.ScratchApiConfig',
celery_1        |  'course.apps.CourseConfig',
celery_1        |  'rest_framework',
celery_1        |  'rest_framework.authtoken',
celery_1        |  'corsheaders',
celery_1        |  'django_tables2',
celery_1        |  'ckeditor',
celery_1        |  'ckeditor_uploader',
celery_1        |  'website',
celery_1        |  'dry_rest_permissions',
celery_1        |  'ordered_model',
celery_1        |  'production_process',
celery_1        |  'guardian',
celery_1        |  'fluent_comments',
celery_1        |  'threadedcomments',
celery_1        |  'crispy_forms',
celery_1        |  'django_comments',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.sites',
celery_1        |  'OJ',
celery_1        |  'bootstrap4',
celery_1        |  'django_filters',
celery_1        |  'notifications',
celery_1        |  'qa',
celery_1        |  'mptt',
celery_1        |  'avatar',
celery_1        |  'taggit',
celery_1        |  'qr_code',
celery_1        |  'pinax.badges',
celery_1        |  'password_reset']
celery_1        | INTERNAL_IPS: []
celery_1        | LANGUAGES: [('zh-hans', '中文简体'), ('en', 'English')]
celery_1        | LANGUAGES_BIDI: ['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
celery_1        | LANGUAGE_CODE: 'zh-hans'
celery_1        | LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE: None
celery_1        | LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN: None
celery_1        | LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME: 'django_language'
celery_1        | LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH: '/'
celery_1        | LOCALE_PATHS: []
celery_1        | LOGGING: {
celery_1        |  }
celery_1        | LOGGING_CONFIG: 'logging.config.dictConfig'
celery_1        | LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL: '/t/index'
celery_1        | LOGIN_URL: '/accounts/login/'
celery_1        | LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL: '/t/'
celery_1        | MANAGERS: []
celery_1        | MEDIA_ROOT: 'media/'
celery_1        | MEDIA_URL: '/media/'
celery_1        | MESSAGE_STORAGE: 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
celery_1        | MIDDLEWARE: ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
celery_1        |  'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
celery_1        |  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
celery_1        |  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
celery_1        |  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
celery_1        |  'scratch_api.middleware.one_session_per_user_middleware',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
celery_1        |  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
celery_1        | MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES: ['django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
celery_1        |  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware']
celery_1        | MIGRATION_MODULES: {
celery_1        |  }
celery_1        | MONTH_DAY_FORMAT: 'F j'
celery_1        | NUMBER_GROUPING: 0
celery_1        | PASSWORD_HASHERS: '********'
celery_1        | PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS: '********'
celery_1        | PREPEND_WWW: False
celery_1        | PROFANITIES_LIST: '********'
celery_1        | REST_FRAMEWORK: {
celery_1        |     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (   'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',),
celery_1        |     'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',)}
celery_1        | ROOT_URLCONF: 'API.urls'
celery_1        | SECRET_KEY: '********'
celery_1        | SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER: False
celery_1        | SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF: False
celery_1        | SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS: False
celery_1        | SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD: False
celery_1        | SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS: 0
celery_1        | SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER: None
celery_1        | SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT: []
celery_1        | SECURE_SSL_HOST: None
celery_1        | SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT: False
celery_1        | SERVER_EMAIL: 'root@localhost'
celery_1        | SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS: 'default'
celery_1        | SESSION_COOKIE_AGE: 1209600
celery_1        | SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN: None
celery_1        | SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY: False
celery_1        | SESSION_COOKIE_NAME: 'sessionid'
celery_1        | SESSION_COOKIE_PATH: '/'
celery_1        | SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE: False
celery_1        | SESSION_ENGINE: 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
celery_1        | SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE: True
celery_1        | SESSION_FILE_PATH: None
celery_1        | SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST: False
celery_1        | SESSION_SERIALIZER: 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
celery_1        | SETTINGS_MODULE: 'API.settings'
celery_1        | SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT: 'Y/m/d G:i:s'
celery_1        | SHORT_DATE_FORMAT: 'm/d/Y'
celery_1        | SIGNING_BACKEND: 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
celery_1        | SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS: []
celery_1        | SITE_ID: 2
celery_1        | STATICFILES_DIRS: 
celery_1        |     ('/home/django/API/static/',)
celery_1        | STATICFILES_FINDERS: ['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
celery_1        |  'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
celery_1        | STATICFILES_STORAGE: 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
celery_1        | STATIC_ROOT: None
celery_1        | STATIC_URL: '/static/'
celery_1        | TEMPLATES: [{'APP_DIRS': True,
celery_1        |   'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
celery_1        |   'DIRS': ['/home/django/API/templates',
celery_1        |            '/home/django/API/html'],
celery_1        |   'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
celery_1        |                                      'django.template.context_processors.request',
celery_1        |                                      'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
celery_1        |                                      'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
celery_1        |                                      'django.template.context_processors.request']}}]
celery_1        | TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS: []
celery_1        | TEST_RUNNER: 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
celery_1        | THOUSAND_SEPARATOR: ','
celery_1        | TIME_FORMAT: 'P'
celery_1        | TIME_INPUT_FORMATS: ['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
celery_1        | TIME_ZONE: 'Asia/Shanghai'
celery_1        | USE_ETAGS: False
celery_1        | USE_I18N: True
celery_1        | USE_L10N: True
celery_1        | USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR: False
celery_1        | USE_TZ: True
celery_1        | USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST: False
celery_1        | USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT: False
celery_1        | WSGI_APPLICATION: 'API.wsgi.application'
celery_1        | X_FRAME_OPTIONS: 'SAMEORIGIN'
celery_1        | YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT: 'F Y'
celery_1        | is_overridden: <bound method Settings.is_overridden of <Settings "API.settings">>
celery_1        | task_serializer: 'json'
celery_1        | accept_content: ['json', 'pickle']
celery_1        |
```

However, when I submit a task which should return a result, the stack trace is as follows:

```
python_1        | Internal Server Error: /OJ/submit/
python_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
python_1        |     sock = self._connect()
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494, in _connect
python_1        |     raise err
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, in _connect
python_1        |     sock.connect(socket_address)
python_1        | OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
python_1        | 
python_1        | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
python_1        | 
python_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2165, in _execute
python_1        |     return command(*args)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 563, in send_command
python_1        |     self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 538, in send_packed_command
python_1        |     self.connect()
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
python_1        |     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
python_1        | redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
python_1        | 
python_1        | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
python_1        | 
python_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 439, in connect
python_1        |     sock = self._connect()
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 494, in _connect
python_1        |     raise err
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 482, in _connect
python_1        |     sock.connect(socket_address)
python_1        | OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
python_1        | 
python_1        | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
python_1        | 
python_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 414, in _reraise_as_library_errors
python_1        |     yield
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 736, in send_task
python_1        |     self.backend.on_task_call(P, task_id)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 189, in on_task_call
python_1        |     self.result_consumer.consume_from(task_id)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 75, in consume_from
python_1        |     return self.start(task_id)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 57, in start
python_1        |     self._consume_from(initial_task_id)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 82, in _consume_from
python_1        |     self._pubsub.subscribe(key)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2229, in subscribe
python_1        |     ret_val = self.execute_command('SUBSCRIBE', *iterkeys(new_channels))
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2161, in execute_command
python_1        |     self._execute(connection, connection.send_command, *args)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2172, in _execute
python_1        |     connection.connect()
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
python_1        |     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
python_1        | redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
python_1        | 
python_1        | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
python_1        | 
python_1        | Traceback (most recent call last):
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
python_1        |     response = get_response(request)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
python_1        |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
python_1        |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
python_1        |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
python_1        |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
python_1        |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
python_1        |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
python_1        |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
python_1        |   File "/home/django/API/OJ/ajax_views.py", line 30, in post
python_1        |     task = judge.delay(submission.id)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 413, in delay
python_1        |     return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 536, in apply_async
python_1        |     **options
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 737, in send_task
python_1        |     amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
python_1        |     self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 419, in _reraise_as_library_errors
python_1        |     sys.exc_info()[2])
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vine/five.py", line 178, in reraise
python_1        |     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 414, in _reraise_as_library_errors
python_1        |     yield
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 736, in send_task
python_1        |     self.backend.on_task_call(P, task_id)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 189, in on_task_call
python_1        |     self.result_consumer.consume_from(task_id)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 75, in consume_from
python_1        |     return self.start(task_id)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 57, in start
python_1        |     self._consume_from(initial_task_id)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 82, in _consume_from
python_1        |     self._pubsub.subscribe(key)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2229, in subscribe
python_1        |     ret_val = self.execute_command('SUBSCRIBE', *iterkeys(new_channels))
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2161, in execute_command
python_1        |     self._execute(connection, connection.send_command, *args)
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 2172, in _execute
python_1        |     connection.connect()
python_1        |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 442, in connect
python_1        |     raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
python_1        | kombu.exceptions.OperationalError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
```

I was very confused for I have modifed the `CELERY_BACKEND_URL` to `redis://redis:6379/0`. redis is the hostname in docker-compose, but it seems that celery is trying to connecting to localhost. I try to deploy all of them without docker, and modify `CELERY_BACKEND_URL` backto 127.0.0.1 and everything works fine. I also try to connect to redis using python redis library on both python docker and celery docker, and redis is available in both dockers.

Comment: Did you manage how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? Facing a similar issue with Docker, Flask, Celery and Redis.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to set them in the same docker network for first then check if they can see each other, after a run of your docker-compose try a `docker exec -it celery curl redis:6379` 
other thing you can check is `docker exec -it redis curl localhost:6379` with `/0` and `/1` then if everything is okay in this check it is a conf issue probably, otherwise well maybe your redis is starting incorrectly or your containers don't sees each other and then you have to investigate a bit more but the first thing to check is that all your services are running correctly and your containers can sees each others

Comment: When you say that if you take everything out of docker it works with replacing redis by 127.0.0.1
There is 2 differences the fist thing is in the docker way you declare celery and redis as 2 entity so it will be 2 different machine, celery may not look for something outside of it own localhost which may cause you this issue.
The other one is when checking with 127.0.0.1 you don't check if redis accept connection from external machines.

Comment: As a workaround you could write a dockerFile of only one container containing all your required services, if of course you don't specifically want to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

Link your python container to your redis container, instead of the celery container.

When you create a task in your Django application, it writes the task to redis. The celery worker then reads from redis, and vice versa for the results.